# How to make a POST HTTPs (with JSON) request in Android?

Tags: android, https

I am looking for a way how to make a POST (login) https request in android.  How to make sure that the code don't trust self-signed/invalid certs. The input to the request needs to be in the following format:

```
{
"udid": DEVICE_ID
"email": "email@email.com",
"password": "password"
}
```

I need to make the auth call to this address format:

```
https://api.ADDRESS.com/v1/auth
```

Please note that I want to use HTTPs request and not HTTP.

Comment: It is not duplicate since I want to use HTTPs and not HTTP...

Comment: OK, but it shuld be the same as your API would get http https respectively

Comment: I am not sure it is the same. I need to generate certificates in order to make the secure HTTPs connection and I dont know how to do that...

Comment: Why dont you just go and pay for certificates (e.g. Comodo), install them and call your api as usual? You dont need to generate CA by yourself. Or am I missunaderstanding?

Comment: [OkHttp doesn't support HTTPS?](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS)

Comment: Thank you for the link @Knossos but isnt this process supported only by Android 5+? I need to support at least KitKat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use volley/retrofit library for parsing json.

example @
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: I wanted to use OkHTTP library, since it is less complex than the one that you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using OkHTTP after researching if it is secure to use in my case:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final MediaType JSON
    = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private JSONObject responseJson;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



final JSONObject myJson = new JSONObject();
try {
    myJson.put("udid","c376e418-da42-39fb-0000-d821f1fd2804");
    myJson.put("email","email
    myJson.put("password","password");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Your code goes here
               String response =  post("https://ADDRESS/v1/auth", myJson.toString());
                responseJson = new JSONObject(response);
                String message = responseJson.getString("message");
                String token = responseJson.getString("token");
                Log.d(TAG,"Response message: " + message);
                Log.d(TAG,"Response token: " + token);
                Log.d("MainActivity",response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();

}

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(body)
        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
return response.body().string();
}
}
```